# Bitrix API добавление в корзину

Tags: битрикс

## Добрый день коллеги!

Имеется магазин на Битрикс, он нормально себе функционирует.
Имеется сторонний сервис с несколькими точками дополнительных продаж.
Стоит задача отправлять новые сторонние заказы в Битрикс.
У меня успешно создается новый заказ, с данными заказчика, но не получается заполнить состав заказа.
С левых сервисов приходят артикулы товаров и я никак по ним не могу полноценно заполнить корзину.

И я так понимаю, что алгоритм должен быть такой:
1. Найти товар по его артикулу;
2. Добавить его в корзину.

По первому пункту основной вопрос.

По второму частично...

В API приведены два способа:
`CSaleBasket::Add` и `Add2BasketByProductID`.
Второй метод вообще не отрабатывает, а первый при вызове в таком виде:

```
CSaleBasket::Add(array(
  'PRODUCT_ID' => 297,
  'CURRENCY' => 'RUB',
  'QUANTITY' => 2,
  'LID' => SITE_ID,
  'ORDER_ID' => $order_id,
));
```

Просто добавляет позицию с количеством, но без цены, названия и остальных полей. В чем проблема то?

Comment: Есть пара идей
1. SITE_ID в вашем коде не константа, такое бывает в зависимости от того где пишешь код.
2. Нет подключения модуля, а именно CModule::IncludeModule("sale");
CModule::IncludeModule("catalog");
3 PRODUCT_PROVIDER_CLASS обязательное поле оно как раз и высчитывает цену для товара со всеми скидками по текущему пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/classes/csalebasket/csalebasket__add.php) к методу `CSaleBasket::Add`как раз приведен необходимый пример:

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule("sale"))
{
  $arFields = array(
    "PRODUCT_ID" => 51,
    "PRODUCT_PRICE_ID" => 0,
    "PRICE" => 138.54,
    "CURRENCY" => "RUB",
    "WEIGHT" => 530,
    "QUANTITY" => 1,
    "LID" => LANG,
    "DELAY" => "N",
    "CAN_BUY" => "Y",
    "NAME" => "Чемодан кожаный",
    "CALLBACK_FUNC" => "MyBasketCallback",
    "MODULE" => "my_module",
    "NOTES" => "",
    "ORDER_CALLBACK_FUNC" => "MyBasketOrderCallback",
    "DETAIL_PAGE_URL" => "/".LANG."/detail.php?ID=51"
  );

  $arProps = array();

  $arProps[] = array(
    "NAME" => "Цвет",
    "CODE" => "color",
    "VALUE" => "черный"
  );

  $arProps[] = array(
    "NAME" => "Размер",
    "VALUE" => "1.5 x 2.5"
  );

  $arFields["PROPS"] = $arProps;

  CSaleBasket::Add($arFields);
}
```

Добавление через API происходит только по полям, которые вы методу скармливаете. Вы не передавали методу данные о названии, цене и т.п., поэтому товар у вас и создался только с теми параметрами, которые вы передали. Если передадите нужные параметры, то товар создастся с ними.